# Facebook API: Error with URL while trying to authenticate user

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get this error when trying to authenticate user:

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Here are my settings in the Facebook Developers app settings:

Site URL: http://localhost:8002/oauth_callback/facebook

OAuth redirect_uri: http://localhost:8002/oauth_callback/facebook/

If anyone has any insight or a solution, I'm interested in hearing it.

Comment: And what is the value of the `redirect_uri` parameter in your call to the login dialog?

Comment: It's showering as:  `http://localhost:8002/oauth_callback/facebook`

Comment: Well that doesn’t match the one you specified as valid then – it is missing the trailing slash.

Comment: Well, if I add the trailing slash, I get this:



{ message: 'redirect_uri isn\'t an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.',
  type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 191 }

Comment: Try removing the “valid OAuth redirect_uri” setting completely.

Comment: Still same error. I also have the Client OAuth Login and Embedded browser OAuth Login marked YES.